# Nested fragments on configuration (orientation) change

Tags: android, configuration, orientation, fragment

I am having trouble understanding how Android deals with fragments (particularly nested fragments) on an orientation change.

Say I have an activity `a1` that loads a fragment `f1`. `f1` then loads multiple instances of fragment `f2` into itself in the `oncreateview()` method.

Now my activity `a1` has this in (`oncreate()`):

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
    return;
```

to make sure that multiple instance of `f1` don't get loaded. I do the same sort of thing in `f1` to makes sure duplicate `f2` instances don't get loaded.

However, my class `f1` needs to reference the `f2` instances later on. Currently I am storing them in an ArrayList in the `f1` object, however after an orientation change this ArrayList is empty and I think the `f2` instances will be different objects any way.

So my question is, how is the best way to have nested fragments and to keep a reference to them after an orientation change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FragmentManger to find references to other fragments.

You can an get a reference to another fragment by doing something like:

```
DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
```

or

```
DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my tag");
```

If you have not already seen it take a look at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) blog post.

In your case where you have multiple instances of the same fragment you can set a tag when you create the fragment and use that instead of the id when looking for the fragment.